# detect format of date and convert it to exact format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Tags: c#, winforms, date-conversion

I have method to convertDatefromExcelToSQL which take date value from excel file and convert it to exact format "yyyy-MM-dd"
the problem occured when date format in the PC different from the formate i declared
I want to modify my method to detect date format and convert it to exact format "yyyy-MM-dd"

```
        public static string convertDatefromExcelToSQL(string excelDate)
        {
            string sdat = "";
            DateTime dat;
            sdat = ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelDate)) ? sdat : excelDate);
            if (MIB.IsDouble(sdat))
            {
                dat = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(sdat));
            }
            else
            {
                if (sdat.Contains(":"))
                {
                    sdat = sdat.Split(' ')[0];
                }
                dat = DateTime.ParseExact(sdat, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            return dat.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
```

```
      public static bool IsDouble(string text)
        {
            Double num = 0;
            bool isDouble = false;

            // Check for empty string.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return false;
            }

            isDouble = Double.TryParse(text, out num);

            return isDouble;
        }
```

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values, in C#, SQL Server *and* Excel. Instead of trying to parse a string without know the format, *avoid* converting the date into a string in the first place. Excel stores dates using its own binary format, which *is* handled by every Excel-reading library, eg Epplus, ClosedXML, ExcelDataReader, *and* the OLEDB driver. Where does the data come from, and why was it converted to a string?

Comment: In Excel dates are stored in the OADate format - an integer offset from 1899-12-30 and a fractional part that specifies the time. `DateTime.FromOADate` can convert that value but you typically **don't** need it, because libraries will convert it automatically. You could use eg `ExcelDataReader` and pass the `IDataReader` it produces directly to `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer` to import Excel data directly into SQL Server without any conversions

Comment: In any case, `convertDatefromExcelToSQL` doesn't do what it says. It doesn't produce a SQL date, it produces a string that may or may not represent a date. ADO.NET, on which all data access libraries are built, works just fine with .NET's `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` types. If you use strings instead of dates with ADO.NET, you have a serious bug. If you generate SQL queries by string concatenation for example you're vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: It's tricky to detect the date format when the excel can originate from different "cultures".  It would be best if you first tried to determine the "culture" of the excel file by excluding those origins for which dates are invalid.   For example, if you have dates that start with figures that are bigger than 12, then you know you're not in US Culture. And if you find the second figure to be bigger than 12, then you probably are ... in US Culture.   This detection should occur before you start processing the bulk of the excel file by reading the dates until you have detected the culture.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string CDtStr(object v)
        {
            string lReturnValue = string.Empty;
            DateTime lOutDateTime = new DateTime();
            if (v != null)
            {
                if (v != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(v.ToString(), out lOutDateTime))
                        lReturnValue = lOutDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                }
            }
            return lReturnValue;
        }
```